# how access to inherited class variable in python

Tags: python, class, variables

I am new to python and I try to understand witring small pieces of code, especially about constructor overloading and class variable. I wrote this to test:

```
class parent:
    # class variable
    numberOfInstance = 0
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        # an instance variable
        self._instVar1 = arg1
        parent.numberOfInstance += 1
        # self.__class__.numberOfInstance += 1

class child(parent):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        # an instance variable for child
        self._instVar2 = arg2
        super().__init__(arg1)

p1 = parent('an arg')
p2 = parent('an arg')
p3 = child('an arg','another' )
print (p2.numberOfInstance)
print (p3.numberOfInstance)
print (child.numberOfInstance)
print (parent.numberOfInstance)
```

The result is as I expected: 3,3,3,3 but when I comment the line
`parent.numberOfInstance += 1` and uncomment the line
`self.__class__.numberOfInstance += 1` changing the way to access the
class variable, the result is :

```
2
3
3
2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

it seems, for me, very strange because the class variable seems to be duplicate and update in "one
way" mode. I understand that in the second version the class is *child* but the variable referenced is the parent variable because incrementation works well.

Comment: The first time you did `self.__class__.numberOfInstance += 1` from an instance of `child`, you read the current value from `parent`, incremented it, and wrote a new class variable in `child`.  From that point onward, both classes have their own independent versions of this class variable.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. this is very strange behavior for me, coming from the java world. Read the value in parent class and create a new one in child ...